# Implementing CQRS in PHP

Tags: php, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm researching about CQRS pattern and our team wants to develop a system based on CQRS in PHP.

I know we can simulate event system in PHP, but I found that CQRS implements better/easier if the programming language would be event based (I'm not sure about this).

I have two questions:

1. I want to know that if we develop our system by CQRS pattern in PHP could be reliable or switch to other(event-based) programming language give us more consistency?
2. what kind of benefits CQRS has in micro-services system? is there any other pattern that reliable and easier to implements?

Answer (score 7):

The language you use doesn't really matter that much for CQRS. Commands and Queries are really simple objects, so you can use PHP if you want. Choose what the developers are familiar with.

When using microservices, CRQS can be really useful when combined with Event Sourcing : microservice A handles Commands and stores Events in an Event Store,  while microservice B handle events, updates the query database and handle Queries. That way your services can be scaled independently, and your business logic is easier to manage.

Answer (score -2):

I don't recommend you to use PHP for building a CQRS. The first question that you should ask yourself is, "what are the reasons why you need to implement an event-sourcing technology like CQRS?"

If the answer is because you need to have an architecture that allows you to distribute all your systems in a more efficient way, you should reconsider to use PHP. It runs in a single-thread processor and it has so many limits.

During a couple of months, we have been working in a PHP project based in CQRS, but at the end of the day, we were struggling with a lot of issues related to the performance. Finally, we discover the functional programming with Elixir and we decided to give up an opportunity.

During multiple months I was reading a lot of information about CQRS and I found to Martin Fowler, who is one of the contributors more relevant in the microservices world. And even he recommend highly to use a functional programming language to do event-sourcing.

However, if you have been decided to use PHP to build a CQRS project, you can give a chance and test it by yourself.

Conversely, if you are interested in using Elixir, you can start by reading some real examples https://leanpub.com/buildingconduit/read which is a blog based site using Elixir with CQRS + Commanded library.

Comment: 1) Sorry, CQRS has nothing to do with Event Sourcing. It is very usable on its own independenly. 2) PHP works very well for CQRS implementation.